# Component included with cq:include not editable

Tags: jsp, aem, aem-6

I'm currently migrating a CQ5 website to AEM 6.3 and I'm having trouble with a component that is included via `<cq:include>`. It shows no edit bars whatsoever - not in Touch UI and neither in Classic UI.

I'm including the component in my JSP page template like this:

```
<cq:include path="stageteaser" resourceType="my-project/components/stageteaser"/>
```

The component has a `cq:htmlTag`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    cq:tagName="div"
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    class="cq-stageteaser"
    id="cq-stageteaser"/>
```

I also use two dialog configurations - one for Classic UI and one for Touch UI - under [`/apps/my-project/components/stageteaser/dialog.xml`](https://gist.github.com/thobens/a82e1896168f2a94ec1a37adf4784a4c) and [`/apps/my-project/components/stageteaser/_cq_dialog/.content.xml`](https://gist.github.com/thobens/6a9b84c9a50365073b16f9eb0f43169e).

The component gets correctly rendered (since content is already present), but there are no edit bars in both UIs.

I tried:

- removing the `cq:htmlTag`
- reducing the dialog to one textfield
- removing the content of the component
- putting the component into a parsys

but no luck so far.

**UPDATE:**

I managed to get it working now by including a parsys instead of the component and putting the component in there. But that would require that content is migrated manually (or somehow automatically), but this seems to be a somewhat ugly workaround.

Comment: Note: I also don't see any hints in the generated HTML that the edit bar is invisible. There is just no code related to editing this specific component.

Comment: shouldn't have to be in a parsys to edit it. Has the template been changed ?

Comment: Just some css classes were changed, nothing that should affect the rendering of edit bars, I suppose.